# onProgressUpdate is not working on AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Here I am tried to download audio from server using AsyncTask. The download is successfully completed, onPostExecute working fine, But onProgressUpdate is not called, whether i using publishProgrees during stuff in background. Here is my code

```
class DownloadAudioFromURL extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Integer, Boolean> {

        String audiopath=null;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {

            int count;
            try {

                String root = path;
                System.out.println("Downloading");
                URL url = new URL(params[0].path);

                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(root+"/AV_"+String.valueOf(params[0].tsLong)+Utility.AUDIO_FORMAT);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                   publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Log.i("audiodownloading", String.valueOf(values[0]));// this is not print data in console
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isDownload) {
            if (isDownload)
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Audio Downloaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `catch (Exception e)` block isn't getting hit?

Comment: Yes i am sure there are no catch any exceptions